# When building apk in Android Studio, APK size increased by big margin i.e. from 3 mb to 20mb

Tags: android, apk

APK size increased after building, apk size increased from 3 mb to 20mb.
its due to lib as seen in circle.
How to remove these lib files??

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZCp5.png

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "csdevbin.dua"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 6
        versionName "4.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

*My dependencies*

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
implementation 'com.startapp:inapp-sdk:3.6.7'
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
```

Comment: There is no pic above, bad mark down formatting. I went ahead and updated it.

Comment: What makes you think that's a problem? It looks like those are the dependencies needed by your project.

Comment: You can only replace this library by different. It is due to this library use C++ code

Comment: earlier those files were not there...  @Jacob Barnes

Comment: You added some dependency (or dependencies) to your app that contain native code. We cannot tell you what those are from the screenshot. Though, given the name `PdfActivity`, my guess is that they are from a PDF rendering library. Review what you added to the `dependencies` closure in your `app/build.gradle` file.

Comment: Those files can't just appear. You must have added them, either by adding them with dependencies, importing some sdk (jcenter/maven), manually importing a sdk or copying them to your project structure. You will have to backtrack and see what you have done. We can't give you a answer on this unless you provide your gradle, manifest and the java class you last worked on. I would suggest deleting the libs and see what stops working.

Comment: yeah you are right i have used { com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.1'  }.. may be due this, i guess...@CommonsWare

Comment: Udated my gradle file..  lib folder is empty in project structure...  @H.Brooks

Comment: It's not empty in the picture above, anyway, like @CommonsWare mentioned, the reason could be the PDF library. But, I used this library last month and I did not get native files in my libs.

Comment: after going through below post, clearly its due to splitting of APK  https://android.jlelse.eu/controlling-apk-size-when-using-native-libraries-45c6c0e5b70a           but i have not done anything like that @H.Brooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i have used { com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.1' }

That library uses native code to render PDFs. The library's documentation has [a FAQ with a question specifically about your concern](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer#why-resulting-apk-is-so-big).

Comment: Thank You !!!.well times to go through FAQ.... @CommonsWare  thank you once again..

Answer (score 0):

If your code uses these libraries then there is no way to remove them. But you can use [ProGuard](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html) to reduce the size of your app. Can you post your `build.gardle` file?

Comment: I don't think these libs are used in my app ,,,,even after using ProGuard , makes no difference

Comment: You have to look at your build.gradle in order to see your project dependencies

Comment: If you are sure you did not use any if these libs, simply delete the lib folder and see if your app still works

Comment: I have used pdf library, may be due to this, those files are there?? no lib is empty,,, i cant delete as seen like in pic there

Comment: Yes, that was the cause. See your Gradle for future cases my friend

Answer (score 0):

While you generate the signed app, generate as **Bundle**. So Google Play will automatically reduce the size of the app to support the user device. The *PDF Library* contains all the files required for all the devices. So, all those repositories will be packed if you sign as **APK**. Try Bundle.

Comment: This answer is not related to the question. Here the user asks for the possible reason for size growth, not how to make smaller apps